# split function does not return last field

Tags: java, split, tabs

I develop a file import process in database
My files are composed of lines, and each field is separated by a tab.

So I use the java split function:

```
String[] thisLine = line.split("\\t");
```

I have a problem when my last field is empty, so that my line ends with a tab, and then a line break.

Example

```
JFJ[TAB]ge[TAB]10400004V[TAB]31.1[TAB]0[TAB]0[TAB]0[TAB][TAB]90[TAB]
```

The split function does not return the last field. In this case, the split function return 9 fi

have you a solution?

Comment: Not very clear what you want the split to return here. Based on your code, the last field of the array will be `90`. Isn't that what you want? Or are you bothered by the empty field created by the two consecutive tabs?

Comment: @Mena looks like OP expects `split` to return one more empty element after 90

Comment: Use `split("\t", -1)`. Now where is that duplicate explaining it...

Comment: @Pshemo was about to comment the exact same thing, but I'd wait to close as dupe until OP clarifies.

Comment: @Mena I need empty value after lest tab

Comment: @Pshemo and Ivan looks like you were right.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks !!